# Ebay API - possible to auto remove listing if sold on site

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to find out initially if it is possible to remove a listing from Ebay automatically if is sold on the clients website first. Or does this have to be done manually.

I have done a general google search but there doesnt seem to be a clear answer so any points in the right direction would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [EndItem API](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/EndItem.html) for this. It can be done "automatically" if you create an application to do it. Otherwise it won't happen. HTH